# Java thread spontaneously waking up

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I've got a Java thread does something like this:

```
while (running) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (nextVal == null) {
            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        val = nextVal;
        nextVal = null;
    }
    ...do stuff with 'val'...
}
```

Elsewhere I set the value like this:

```
if (val == null) {
    LOG.error("null value");
} else {
    synchronized (lock) {
        nextVal = newVal;
        lock.notify();
    }
}
```

Occasionally (literally once every couple of million times) nextVal will be set to null.  I've tossed in logging messages and I can see that the order of execution looks like this:

1. thread1 sets nextVal to newVal
2. thread1 calls lock.notify()
3. thread2 wakes up from lock.wait()
4. thread2 sets val to nextVal
5. thread2 sets nextVal to null
6. thread2 does stuff with val
7. thread2 calls lock.wait()
8. thread2 wakes up from lock.wait()

   - no other thread has called lock.notify() and thread2 has not been interrupted
9. thread2 sets val to nextVal (which is null)
10. etc.

I've explicitly checked and the lock is waking up a second time, it's not being interrupted.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: +1 for a well-written explanation, but -1 for not reading the Javadoc more carefully :-)

Comment: IIRC, there's no guarantee that a thread won't wake from a wait, while the wait condition is still unsatisfied.  You must always check the condition and re-execute the wait if not satisfied.

Comment: (The reason for this has to do with the complexities of implementing the "wakeup" logic.  Guaranteeing that there is never a spurious wakeup is just about impossible without lots of expensive synchronization.)

Comment: Wow, I do a LOT of threading and this is the first time I've noticed this!  Thanks for all the gentle reminders to re-read the docs :-S

Comment: That's one of the things with threading, you can run something infinity minus delta times fine and it could still contain a bug. I would recommend [JCIP](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/) as the definitive text on threading issues. Due to the inherent complexities of multi-threading one's normal approach is useless, you _cannot_ write and test; as mentioned above it is next to impossible to fully test concurrent code - you **have** to _know_ the common pitfalls beforehand.

Answer (score 4):

Yup, `Thread`s spontaneously wake up. The this is explicitly stated in [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29):

"A thread can also wake up without being notified, interrupted, or timing out, a so-called *spurious wakeup*."

You need to `wait` in a loop. This is also explicitly mentioned in the javadoc:

```
 synchronized (obj) {
     while (<condition does not hold>)
         obj.wait(timeout);
     ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
 }
```

In your case:

```
while (running) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        while (nextVal == null) {
            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                //oh well
            }
        }

        val = nextVal;
        nextVal = null;
    }
    ...do stuff with 'val'...
}
```

Comment: I should note that the 'while (nextVal == null) {' solution wouldn't work for me because I omitted the detail that this thread is stopped via a method that does:

    synchronized (lock) {
        running = true;
        lock.notify();
    }

so I can't spin on 'nextVal == null'.  Instead, I added:

    if (nextVal == null) continue;

before the 'val = nextVal' to ensure that 'running' is checked on each trip through the loop.

Comment: Remove that entriely, make it a `while(true)`. Check the `running` flag somewhere else and `return`. You can even add some logic in the interrupt then you can `interrupt` the `Thread` to stop.

Comment: Yes, interrupts is the right way to stop a running thread. Using a separate `boolean` flag approach is full of pitfalls. Like, I hope `running` is marked `volatile` here!

Answer (score 1):

Spurious wake ups are fairly common and hence it's always advised to `wait()` on a condition within a loop.

Change your code as follows:

```
while (nextVal == null) {
    try {
        lock.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
    }
}
```

Specific to the code you've shared: `while` also helps you avoid the unnecessary overhead of releasing and re-acquiring the same lock when your code hits `continue;`

References:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()

> From the `public final void wait()` documentation:
>   ... interrupts and spurious wakeups are possible, and this method should always be used in a loop:

```
 synchronized (obj) {
     while (<condition does not hold>)
         obj.wait();
     ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a spurious wakeup, but that is not the only possible cause. It is definitely a problem with your logic. You need to put the wait inside a loop that retests for the condition.

When a thread wakes up from the wait, it doesn't have the lock anymore. It *released the lock* when it started waiting, it needs to reacquire the lock before it can proceed. The just-awoken thread may typically be next in line due to thread affinity (which is probably why your code works most of the time), but there is still the chance it's not; another thread can come in and snag the lock, do its thing and leave the nextVal null, before the awoken thread can take the lock. That means the test for null that the thread made before waiting is no longer relevant. You have to go back and test again once you have the lock.

Change the code to use a loop, like:

```
synchronized(lock) {
    while (nextVal == null) {
        lock.wait();
    }
   ...
```

This way the test is made while the thread has the lock, and whatever happens in the block below the while loop can be certain nextVal really isn't null.